# Ember.js: Share object among Controllers or share controller among each other

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

For a route **/dashboard** I have, *DashboardController* & 2 different named outlets in *DashboardView*.

*connectOutlet* of **/dashboard** *Route* looks like following

```
connectOutlets: function(router) {
    var appController = router.get('applicationController');
    appController.connectOutlet('dashboard', {});

    var dashboardController = router.get('dashboardController');
    dashboardController.connectOutlet({
        name: 'dashProjects',
        outletName: 'dashProjects',
        context: App.Project.find()
    });                                     
    dashboardController.connectOutlet({
        name: 'projectSummary',
        outletName: 'projectSummary'
    }); 
}
```

Now on click on item(*Project*) in *DashProjectsView*, *ProjectSummaryView* should be updated.

**What should be ideal way of sharing an object (in this case *Project*) between controllers.**

One way of doing is creating an shared global object in *App.currentProject*, but it defeats the purpose.

I think, *DashboardController* should hold to an object and *DashProjects* and *ProjectSummary* should be accessing it. Any guidance/pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could have a look at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/lib/system/controller.js#L173, and connect dashProjectsController to projectSummaryController.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But where connectController should be written? In connectOutlet?  
For example I have /dashboard and /statistics pages where I need same controller. One way of doing is, I write connect connectController on both route's connectOutlets. Is there any other place or way?

Comment: I think you can do it when application is ready, defining the `App.ready` function. see http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/ slide 31 for an example

Answer (score 1):

```
connectOutlets: function() {
    router.get('dashboardController').connectControllers('projectSummary')
    ... Other code you might have here ...
}

App.DashboardController: Ember.Controller.extend({
    projectSummaryController: null,
    ... Other code in your controller ...
}
```

You can then get hold of your projectSummaryController from your dashboardController.